# Generating a random combination in O(k)?

Tags: combinations, random

I need to generate a "fair" random combination of $k$ items chosen from $n$ choices. All the algorithms I've been able to find so far (reservoir sampling, Fisher-Yates shuffle, ...) are of $O(n)$ complexity or worse.

Is there an algorithm of complexity $O(k)$, also?

Unfortunately I don't have a list of my $n$ choices that I can operate on either. I could build one, but that would be an $O(n)$ operation in itself. So, I am looking for an algorithm that just spits out indices into such a list, but doesn't require it.

A quick update:

Here is what I'm currently thinking about: Let's say we're looking at $5$ choose $3$. Then, the possible combinations are:

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5
```

So, when choosing the first number, I need to pick $1$, $2$ or $3$, with a probability of $\frac{6}{10}$, $\frac{3}{10}$, and $\frac{1}{10}$ respectively. For the second place I then need to choose from either $2$, $3$, and $4$ with probabilities $\frac{3}{6}$, $\frac{2}{6}$, and $\frac{1}{6}$ respectively, or from $3$ and $4$ with probabilities $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ or I can only to choose 4. And so forth...

So, basically, I "only" need two $O(1)$ functions:

- One that tells me, given the numbers chosen so far, what's my denominator in the probability fractions (i.e. what's the range of random number I need to pick from). In the examples above, this function would return $10$ for the first number. For the second number, it would return $6$, $3$, or $1$, depending on whether I chose $1$, $2$, or $3$ respectively for the first number, and so on...
- A function that tells me the number that corresponds to the random "numerator" that I picked. In the example above, the function for the first digit would return $1$ if my random number was between $0$ and $5$ inclusive, $2$ if it was between $6$ and $8$, and $3$ if it was $9$.

I believe that since the numbers are in ascending order, these functions should probably only depend on $n$ minus the last chosen number and are independent of which other numbers were previously chosen. So, at a first rough glance, I don't see any introduction of $O(k)$ or $O(n)$ complexity into these functions, at least not from the parameters they depend on...

Do such functions with $O(1)$ complexity exist?

Comment: Do you consider choosing a single random integer in a range to be $O(1)$?

Comment: @paw88789 I'd think so... Are you thinking of using combinadics? I was looking into that, but to calculate the corresponding combination for a natural number is quite involved. Or do you know of an algorithm that could do that in O(k)?

Comment: Can you do just the first $k$ steps of a Fisher-Yates shuffle, to get your combination?  And would that be $O(k)$?

Comment: @paw88789 If I understood it correctly, the Fisher-Yates shuffle only works if it runs over all elements. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Relation_to_Fisher-Yates_shuffle

Comment: I may be misnaming what I am thinking of.  Start with the list $[1..n]$.  For step $i$ pick a random integer $x$ in $[i..n]$ and swap the list element in position $i$ with the list element in position $x$ (if $x=i$, no swap takes place).  If you do this for $i=1,...,n-1$ you get a fully shuffled list.  If you do it for $i=1,...,k$ you get the first $k$ elements as a partial shuffle.

Comment: @paw88789 The problem is that simply generating the list that you're swapping in is already O(n) ;) Let me add a clarification to that extent to the question.

Comment: A--Yeah, I was afraid of that.  That was one reason I was posting as comments rather than as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wlog, assume that $k \le n/2$. Indeed, if $k > n/2$, then you can instead generate a random combination of $n-k$ items from $n$ items, and inverse it.

Start with an empty set. Repeatedly generate a random number between $1$ and $n$. If this number is not in the set, add it to the set. Repeat until the set contains $k$ elements.

What is the complexity of this algorithm? Since $k \le n/2$, every time you generate a random number, with probability at least half, it will not be in the set. Thus, the expected number of times you generate a number until you insert a new member to the set is $2 = O(1)$. Thus, the expected number of steps is $O(k)$.

Note: "how do you check whether the number is in the set in $O(1)$?": use an external array initially all zeroes. Whenever you add a number, set the corresponding element in the array into 1. After the set contains $k$ elements, reset all those elements of the array back to $0$. This requires using an external array of size O(n), but the same array will be used for any call to the random-generating function, and you still only make $O(k)$ modifications to it.

Alternatively if you don't like array this still works in $O(k \log k)$, using balanced binary tree for the set.

Comment: You can modify this to get an $O(k^2)$ worst-case runtime instead of expected runtime: on the second iteration (let $a$ be the first generated value), generate a random number $b$ from 1 to $n-1$, and add 1 to it if $b\geq a$. In general, on the $i$-th iteration, generate $x$ from 1 to $n-i+1$, go through the previous elements $y$ from least to greatest, and add 1 each time $x \geq y$.

Comment: Actually, it can be $O(k\log k)$ worst-case by using binary search in the set. Call the set $s_1 < s_2 < \cdots < s_i$. On the $(i+1)$-st element, generate $x$ from $1$ to $n-i$, then look for element $s_j$ that satisfies "$s_j \leq (x + j) < s_{j+1}$". Add "$x + j$" to the set.